# Cannot defragment hard disk, error in CSC1.tmp

Tags: windows, defragment, windows-xp-embedded

My computer is running absolutely fine, but when I run the disk fragmentation tool (right-click C:\, then Properies > Tools), the progressbar gets nearly to the end and then pops up an error in the file C:\Windows\CSC\CSC1.tmp.

This fill is not normally visible in Windows Explorer, but if I choose Tools > Folder Options > View, then untick "Hide protected operating system file", I can see the file. This file was old, so I just deleted it.

Still no problem with Windows, however now when I try disk defrag I get an error in C:\Recycler\Dc115.tmp. Neither CSC1.tmp or Dc115.tmp are visible anymore (no matter what settings I choose in Explorer or searching in the registry). I've also tried defragging in Safe Mode. No help.

What gives? Is there any way to resolve this?

Running Windows Embedded Standard (very similar to Windows XP, I think), if that is relevant.

Comment: Have you tried running a disk check yet ('chkdsk', or by using the GUI tool in the drive properties)? This will help determine if there's file-system corruption and/or possible drive failure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran "chkdsk /f" which scheduled a full disk scan at the next reboot. After the reboot there was a sizeable pause where the screen was just black (about 15-20s) then Windows booted up. After this, the defrag works perfectly. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may have file-system corruption.

Run a disk check ('chkdsk', or by using the GUI tool in the drive properties), as this will help determine if there's file-system corruption and/or possible drive failure.

If it reports problems on the drive, run it with the repair option (e.g.: `chkdsk /f`) and after it finishes up try your defrag again (assuming chkdsk reported no fatal/uncorrectable errors).

Comment: This worked in my case, thanks. Don't think the drive is failing, probably a corrupted file.